# How to create multidimensional Arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm considerably new to arraylists and structures that involve multiple dimensions, therefor I would be really greatful if somebody could help me out on this or give me a hint on how to achieve this.

The objective of my program is to create 2 separate arraylists. Each of those two arraylists should have 4 other arraylists as their parameters.

There will be information passed into these child arraylists and this arraylist will be stored back into the parent arraylist.

I've looked up in internet for how to get the structure I'm describing here, but with no results. 
I'm sorry if it is a simple question, but I'm really stuck.

Comment: Have you considered using Maps or a container / wrapper class for these sub-lists?  Also, must they be ArrayList Objects, or can they be treated as List Objects?

Comment: @Rahul I have tried applying method specified bellow as an answer, but I'm getting an error when I compile the code. Saying I don't define the arraylist properly.
I've read as well about lists, maps and hashmaps. But due to lack of knowledge in this field failed to apply.

Comment: @JoshDM Any method that can be applied. Which would fit the objective I've defined. The only reason why I mentioned arraylist is due to some knowledge in the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parent=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> arr1=new ArrayList<String>();
arr1.add("S1");
arr1.add("S2");
arr1.add("S3");
arr1.add("S4");

ArrayList<String> arr2=new ArrayList<String>();
arr2.add("S5");
arr2.add("S6");

ArrayList<String> arr3=new ArrayList<String>();
arr3.add("S7");
arr3.add("S8");
arr3.add("S9");
arr3.add("S10");

ArrayList<String> arr4=new ArrayList<String>();
arr4.add("S11");
arr4.add("S12");

parent.add(arr1);
parent.add(arr2);
parent.add(arr3);
parent.add(arr4);



ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parent2=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

 arr1=new ArrayList<String>();
arr1.add("S1");
arr1.add("S2");
arr1.add("S3");
arr1.add("S4");

 arr2=new ArrayList<String>();
arr2.add("S5");
arr2.add("S6");

 arr3=new ArrayList<String>();
arr3.add("S7");
arr3.add("S8");
arr3.add("S9");
arr3.add("S10");

 arr4=new ArrayList<String>();
arr4.add("S11");
arr4.add("S12");

parent2.add(arr1);
parent2.add(arr2);
parent2.add(arr3);
parent2.add(arr4);
```

Parent and parent2 are your arraylists...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a data structure like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<?> a = list(list("A", "B"), 
                          list("C", "D"), 
                          list("E", "F"), 
                          list("G", "H"));
    ArrayList<?> b = list(list("I", "J"), 
                          list("K", "L"), 
                          list("M", "N"), 
                          list("O", "P"));
}

private static <T> ArrayList<T> list(T... values) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think object/class not `ArrayList` or ...

If I understand well, you have a parent object (lets use some `Parent` class), containing two list (we will call them `first` and `second` but think of something more suited for your context) and each list should contain 4 other lists (lets call them `north`, `east`, `south` and `west`, but once again your context..).

Here we can see some "glitch", mainly because lists are usually not fixed-size, so let's roll back to `first` and `second` and use some new class for them (we call it `FourList`, but context). We now have:

```
class Parent {
    private FourList first;
    private FourList second;
    // getter, setter, ...
}

class FourList {
    private List<?> north;
    private List<?> east;
    private List<?> south;
    private List<?> west;
    // getter, setter, ...
}
```

Short version, cut everything into plain simple piece with meaning in your context

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList arr2 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList arr3 = new ArrayList();
arr3.add("from arr3");
arr2.add(arr3);
arr1.add(arr2);

for(int i=0;i<arr1.size();i++){
    System.out.println("i:"+arr1.get(i));

    for(int j=0;j<((ArrayList)arr1.get(i)).size();j++){
    System.out.println("j:"+((ArrayList)arr1.get(i)).get(j));
    for(int k=0;k<((ArrayList)((ArrayList)arr1.get(i)).get(j)).size();k++){
        System.out.println("j:"+((ArrayList)((ArrayList)arr1.get(i)).get(j)).get(k));
    }
    }

}

output: 
i:[[from arr3]]
j:[from arr3]
k:from arr3
```